# How can you dynamically set a SQL field name based on a concatenation of fields from other tables?

Tags: sql, dynamic, alias

I have two tables. The field names in the projects table are stored in the fieldname table

#### Projects Table

```
RecordID, ProjectID, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4,...,Field20
```

#### FieldNames Table

```
FieldNameID, ProjectID, FieldNumber, FieldName
```

Is it possible to return results from the Projects table where the field name is actually FieldNames.FieldName? Can you concatenate 'Field'+FieldNames.FieldNumber to return the Fieldname and then use that as the alias for Field(x) in Projects?

i.e.: instead of  "Field1" it would be FieldNames.FieldName where Projects.ProjectID=FieldNames.ProjectNames and FieldNumber=1

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with dynamic SQL, or a huge case statement that maps values to fields, or by creating a view that contains each combination and you use the appropriate code in the where clause to get the right rows.

However, in my opinion you are going down completely the wrong path, and helping you go farther without dire warning would be completely irresponsible. So here goes:

The database design you're using is a truly awful design anti-pattern and violates best practice in a particularly smelly way (like "code smell", you have "database smell"). Do not store column names in columns. It is wrong. It will hurt. It will make your database evil. Professionals will secretly and loudly laugh at it. I am deadly serious.